# Upgraded to SDK2.3, now maps won't display

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

My fault for being impatient but I've just installed Gingerbread SDK and the new ADT plugin for Eclipse on Eclipse 3.5
Now when I run an existing Google maps project which has worked fine on 2.2, I see no map displayed when running in Eclipse, just like as if I had the wrong debug maps API key. (I just get the grey screen and the Google logo bottom left.)

I have the build path using the old Google APIs [Android 2.1 update1] just like it was before and the target AVD is Google API level 7 as before. (I also created a new Google API level 7 and that doesn't work either).

It seems that something in the backward compatibility is broken somewhere. The only thing in logcat which ***may*** be of significance is:

```
12-06 19:10:31.095: ERROR/ActivityThread(231): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
```

where 231 is the PID of my application.

All suggestions will be gratefully received

(I have checked with Google that my debug API key is still OK)

(I tried to add a Gingerbread tag to this question, but don't have enough rep. Perhaps someone would like to add one?)

For Octavian:

part of manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

default.properties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
# 
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
# 
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "build.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Indicates whether an apk should be generated for each density.
split.density=false
# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:7
apk-configurations=
```

I imported the sample MapsDemo project from the addon, pasted my API key in the xml and see this:

```
12-06 21:55:16.722: ERROR/MapActivity(492): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

in the logcat (492 is the PID of the sample app, I still get just the grey screen - no map)
I wonder if it's relevant?

**UPDATE**

It's not just the maps application. **Every single application that requires network connectivity on every AVD (newly created or pre-existing) fails to connect.** The built in browser can't find google. The build in app called "maps" comes up with "loading", then "Network failure - This application requires a working data connection".

What have I done? Please suggest how can I fix it?

Comment: Im guessing you did build over Gingerbread with googles api, and not just regular 2.3 android, right?

Comment: Yes I added the new Google jar (level 9)

Comment: Could you please post the `<uses-sdk ... />` part of your `AndroidManifest.xml` and also the content of your `default.properties`.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the Emulator and recreating it? Just in case.

Comment: I've made several new AVDs 1.6, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 - none of them work, nor do the old ones that were there when I just had 2.2. It's exactly the same in Eclipse Helios too. Helios worked OK except that the code completion was very slow as reported by many others. I only upgraded to 2.3, hoping that the Helios problems were fixed, now I'm wondering how to back out

Comment: This really doesnt make any sense, I tried to reproduce this problem without success, 2.3 is working fine on my computer. How about getting rid of eclipse and the SDK and doing a fresh download of Eclipse 3.5, the ADT, and the SDK?

Comment: It's not Eclipse after all. I posted another question today, regarding why an emulator created from the command line has no network connectivity for it's built in apps. My SDK is broken somehow

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly on my AVD. Make sure to test it against the correct platform. That means make sure to create a 2.3 Google APIs AVD.

Comment: I tried on a new 2.3 AVD first of all, that didn't work. If I link with 2.1 jars in the build, then it should run on a 2.1 AVD. After all when I installed 2.2 I could still run the app on a 1.6 AVD as long as I had 1.6 as the jars in the build properties. It's broken the backward compatibility for me

Comment: Doesn't really make sense to me. I'm more than 100% certain that you just didn't test it against a Google APIs (SDK version 9) but against a SDK version 9 AVD.

Comment: How can you be 100% certain of that, when you can't see my machine? I know the difference between Android 2.3 and an Android 2.3 plus google AVD. In any case it should run on a Google level 7 AVD when built with the 2.1 maps and android jars. It did before I upgraded!

Comment: @NickT: Ah got your now. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'll check that in a second.

Comment: @NickT: Just checked. Compiles and runs perfectly on a 2.1 AVD too.

Comment: @Octavian: added uses-sdk and the default.properties to question