# Android Emulator - No internet connectivity

Tags: android, connection, emulation

I know that there are several threads posted about this issue, however I believe my problem to be a bit different:

I had my Android emulator working without any problems (using Eclipse plugin). I could start the emulator, run applications, and those apps would be able to connect to my computers internet.  I then updated the Android SDK's (as I wanted to try out my application on 2.2).  Since the update, the emulator will not connect to the internet.  If I go to the browser, the page will not be displayed.  I have tried everything - reverting back to the 2.1 SDK, even completely reinstalling Eclipse + Android, and the issue still remains.

I know that I have no firewall/proxy type issues. What could be causing this?  Does anyone have any ideas? I'd greatly appreciate it...

Thanks!

Comment: changing the DNS address of the working machine solved my problem. I am using windows 7

Comment: @newcomer please mention how to change it, I'm struggling for 2 days now, sometimes the net works and sometime not, or at least give some useful links

Comment: I am not sure and can't remember well after this long, it might be http://mintywhite.com/windows-7/change-dns-server-windows-7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to my question:

[Upgraded to SDK 2.3 - now no emulators have connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376553/upgraded-to-sdk-2-3-now-no-emulators-have-connectivity)

should help

*In particular "It doesn't seem to like systems that have 'obtain DNS automatically' set. I changed it to manual set to Norton's Public DNS and the emulator browser works straight off "*

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you so much, you have stopped a big headache!