# Android emulator no internet connectivity

Tags: android, emulation, connectivity

I'm running under windows xp sp3 and i have no firewall, no proxy, my internet connection works perfectly but android emulator have no connection (browser and app), i've tried some solutions like  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899967/android-emulator-no-internet-connectivity) but infortunately not work. For information, my emulator used to work and this problem occurs suddenly..

Please help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start your from command prompt prompt like

`your_path_of_android_sdk\tools\emulator -avd <AVD Name> -dns-server 8.8.8.8`

I think this will help you out as a temporary  solution.

Comment: thanks, that worked well, but i want to know if it's a bug that will be solved or we have to do with this ?

Comment: I think it is a bug if you upgrade SDK to 2.3.

Comment: It worked for me! Faced the problem after upgrading AVD in API 25.

Answer (score 0):

try to go to Settings > Wireless & Networks > Enable Wifi
(if you get an error, restart emulator till it works ( its a bug in emulator, we all have this)

Comment: thanks for your help, but I tried many times and unfortunately didn't work :(