# No Internet connection on any emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am not getting internet connection in the android emulator. I have tried all solutions from the following links,
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376553/upgraded-to-sdk-2-3-now-no-emulators-have-connectivity),
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437366/android-emulator-internet-access),
[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801204/android-emulator-no-internet-connectivity)
 But Still I am not getting internet connection in emulator.
There are no proxy settings on my machine.Windows firewall is off. How to fix this issue.

Comment: Press F8 to toggle 3g in your emulator. You will see a 3g symbol on status bar if your internet is enabled

Comment: check firewall settings in your computer..

Comment: @AndroSelva, 3g symbol is showing, but if I launch browser or maps app in emulator , they r not getting internet

Answer (score 4):

Even if by pressing F8 your internet connection is not working. Just make sure when you have started your emulator your machine is already connected with internet.
If you start emulator first and then connect to internet, it will not work in your emulator.

Answer (score 1):

try this it worked for me.

Run -> Run Configurations -> Target -> Network Latency -> EDGE

Answer (score 0):

try the following one:

Kill the adb : kill-adb server

than start the adb : start-adb server

than enter the following command : C:\ProgramFiles\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\emulator -avd -dns-server 8.8.8.8

Comment: If I run the command ,I am getting "DNS server name '8.8.8.
8' resolved to 8.8.8.8:55"
"createRenderThread failed to connect"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Run -> Run Configurations -> Select Target tab -> Select your Target Emulator Device and in **Additional Emulator Command Line Options** field type **-dns-server x.x.x.x** (x.x.x.x is the IP address of your DNS server). Restart Emulator and have fun :-)