# Android Emulator 2.3.3 with No Internet Connection

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgraded to SDK 2.3 - now no emulators have connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376553/upgraded-to-sdk-2-3-now-no-emulators-have-connectivity)

I just updated my Android SDK to latest version which has come up as 2.3.3 and now when I visit any website using its Emulator browser, it say "Browser can not load the web page because there is no internet connection." Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376553/upgraded-to-sdk-2-3-now-no-emulators-have-connectivity)

Comment: what's the workaround for this?

Comment: Did you check the answer posted in the link?

Comment: no I actually reverted back to 2.2 for temp