# Android: Unable to connect to internet using Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a LAN internet connection and also a wireless connection.
For the past few weeks, I was able to connect to internet using the Android emulator.
Today it stopped working. Unable to find the reason.

Saw other questions on stack overflow which talk about proxy. Don't know whether
wireless connections are also behind proxy and if there is where to find it.

Comment: Emulator Details: Target: Android 2.2 Platform: 2.2 API Level:8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question

[Upgraded to SDK 2.3 - now no emulators have connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376553/upgraded-to-sdk-2-3-now-no-emulators-have-connectivity)

might be of help, as may be my final comment to the answer.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a ton Nick! Set the DNS to 8.8.8.8 and it worked like a charm! :-)

Answer (score 1):

in emulator
settings - wireless & networks - mobile networks - access point names - telkila

set proxy and port

OR

Run - Run Configurations.. - select application from Android Application - Target tab -
Additional Emulator Command Line Options

-http-proxy http://:/