# Connect Android emulator to the internet(Ubuntu)

Tags: android, emulation

I'm developping a SIP application, and i must have a connection to test if it works or not.
I tried to verify the connection by opening a webpage in the emulator but i have an error Web page not available(=> no connection). I'm on Ubuntu, how can i please configure the emulator to have an internet connection. Thank you very much.

Comment: when using Android SDK + Emulator it should connect to the internet if a Internet Connection is available on you computer. Do you see a 3G logo in the emulator?

Comment: @Tivie: no i'm not seeing the 3G logo in the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no experience with Ubuntu but had similar problems with Windows a while back. The answers to my question [Upgraded to SDK 2.3 - now no emulators have connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376553/upgraded-to-sdk-2-3-now-no-emulators-have-connectivity)

just *might* be of some use.

Answer (score 1):

> no i'm not seeing the 3G logo in the emulator

This means that the emulator is unable to reach the Internet when it starts up. It appears to make this determination around the time the home screen or keyguard appears.

Normally, this just works, with the occasional failure due to Internet traffic or similar external issues. Hence, the first thing to do is simply restart the emulator.

If the problem is persistent, then there is some proxy server or firewall that is interfering with your Internet access. You may wish to read [this section of the Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking), particularly the "Local Networking Limitations" and "Using the Emulator with a Proxy" portions.