# Android Emulator net Problem

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am not getting the internet in the android emulator browser. But i am getting the net in my pc's browser.. What may the reason for that?

Comment: See this thread if it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a bug if you upgrade SDK to 2.3.

Start your emulator  from command prompt prompt like

```
your_path_of_android_sdk\tools\emulator -avd <AVD Name> -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

This will help you out as a temporary solution.

Comment: This is an open bug in android framework. See the link http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13031

Answer (score 1):

set your system time & date properly, sometimes it creates problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a proxy you need to set the environment variable http_proxy to point to your proxy URL to enable internet in the emulator

Answer (score 0):

The answers to this question might help: [Upgraded to SDK 2.3 - now no emulators have connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376553/upgraded-to-sdk-2-3-now-no-emulators-have-connectivity)

Answer (score 0):

Use **https SSL secure connection url in android emulator** browser, because by default emulator get PC information about proxy.

Another I got the common problem with **com.android.browser** wanting to force close every time I tried to use the Internet app. By mistake I found and easier solution than hard resetting the phone.

Under **Settings/Application/Manage applications** you have a tab saying All. Under that tab you’ll find the Internet app. Click on it and you’ll find a button called Clear data. I don’t know what kind of data you lose but now I don’t get the force close message at least. I didn't have to backup everything, doing a hard reset and performing the update again.