# Internet Issue in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Kindly read every thing and please help me out friends.

I know there are many posts regarding this. I am totally fed up doing all the steps that are insisted in the web sites. And please friends [Internet Issue in android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346357/internet-issue-in-android-emulatorI) need your help. My problem is slightly different.

**My android sdk is android-sdk-linux_x86
I am ubuntu 10.04 lucid lynx user.
I use wlan0 
and my proxy is http://192.168.3.254:8080/.
My Android Platform is ANDROID 2.2**

New to android.

My issue is i got internet when i installed android emulator but afterwards i am not getting. Friendssss.... Please help me. I am banging my head since 3 days. Please kindly help.
i have done this 
Set the path"/home/sindhu/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools","/home/sindhu/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/ in ~/.bashrc file in root and normal mode

adb works fine.
$/home/sindhu/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/emulator -avd MyAndroid -http-proxy http://192.168.3.254:8080/ 
from my command line / terminal.

I am in bad need of help. I even did this. After emulator starts i open settings->Wireless and Networks->MobileNetworks->Clicked on Data Roaming then I created a new APN for myself.

But still no use !!!!!!!!!!!

Thank You,
Sindhu

Comment: Has it been working with a direct internet connection and now that you use a proxy it is not working anymore?

Comment: @Dynosios  :   It was working when i started my emulator for the first time after installing. But later it did not work.I have done all the setting in my system to connect to internet. So i am not knowing anything. Kindly help

Comment: @user370305  Basically my project  needs this. # Running rsync command inside android program
# Accessing internet inside android program
# Copying state info of applications to some remote system.

Comment: try to use http post within your application for sync it with remote system. and in http post's url give the your url of 192.168.3.254:8080.

Comment: I dint get you. Can u elaborate

Comment: C basically i installed rsync which need ssh to conenct to remote system. So  to connect to remote system i need internet. I installed ConnectBot. It is of no use.No internet.

Comment: You also need to select your new APN as the active one - did you remember that?

Answer (score 1):

I think if your developing system has a internet connecton activated then you do not need to do extra setting for your emulator's internet.

Comment: Ya thanks for the reply. First i got the internet directly. But now i dont know whats wrong . I am not getting.

Comment: can you use the internet directly in your application.? means you are work on android application in which you can not connect to internet?

Comment: No presently, I dint write any application. I am just doing from terminal only. And my system works fine with internet but not the emulator

Comment: can you tried your emulator's inbuilt browser? check it, give any url for checking connectivity..

Comment: ya i checked it from there only. I am not getting it.Where else can i check?  Thanks

Comment: try to start your emulator and then write any url in its browser. if its display the page of website then its running normally.

Comment: Its not running my friend. It is the main issue

Comment: If you have a proxy, as the OP does, you do need to set the APN proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the proxy values in the APN itself? One other thing that most people forget is saving the settings after you change the APN values.

Answer (score 0):

It might possibly be your DNS settings.
Have a look at the answer to this question of mine
[Upgraded to SDK 2.3 - now no emulators have connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376553/upgraded-to-sdk-2-3-now-no-emulators-have-connectivity). Setting the DNS to 8.8.8.8 fixed it for me, albeit in Windows not Linux.