# No internet in android Pie emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-9.0-pie

Recently started using Android Pie emulator. Apart from the previous emulators , the latest emulator was not connected to the internet. Tried to turn on mobile data and to configure dns from command line. Still no connectivity in emulator.

[image]

Comment: May be its because the emulator can't find the DNS your computer is currently using.

Comment: Refer these links:- 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736038/android-emulator-not-able-to-access-the-internet 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376553/upgraded-to-sdk-2-3-now-no-emulators-have-connectivity  hope this helps you

Comment: I tried everything .Got the answer. New emulator has wifi simulated. not cellular network.Thanks for your help.:)

Comment: Happy to help you..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The new Android Pie emulator has a simulated wifi connection to provide internet access. The previous versions were providing internet through simulated cellular network.

Simply go to wifi settings, there you can find a wifi connection named **AndroidWifi**. Connect to the network and it will start using the system's internet connection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the DNS on your dev machine on 8.8.8.8, it solved the problem for me.

Comment: This is a solution to OP's issue?

Answer (score 0):

Main cause for this is because of DNS server setting. just change it using below simple steps and you should be get working.

Go to network and internet option-> enter image description here

click on Etherenet or wifi(for which you are connected) option -> enter image description here

Click on change adapter option -> enter image description here

Right click on the network for which you have connected. enter image description here

A dialog box will be opened and just click on Internet protocal version (TCP/IPv4) option. enter image description here

Another dialog box will be opened and there just neglect the first set about the IP address (Keep as it is set) and click radio button of Use the following DNS server addresses: and enter as 8.8.8.8 in Preferred DNS server: and 8.8.4.4 in Alternate DNS server: enter image description here

Now you can open your emulator whenever and you will get internet in the android emulators.

For detailed pictures info you can just refer answer by this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/54141667/8746415

Thank you.